# I'm trying to print the value of sql query but it is print different value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a stored procedure where i got stuck and i'm trying to print the value of REC_STAT but I'm getting blank value on other hand when every I'm trying to get the vlaue of like ab, ab1 and ver_dosage I'm able to print the values but problem with REC.REC_STAT it is print blank value through dbms_output.put_line but it is print like this REC.

```
declare

EXT_PHARMA_ID varchar2(10) := 'MCL_051270';

begin

TEST_SP('T_MCL_051270_20160314_0019057','MCL',EXT_PHARMA_ID,'0');

end;
```

/

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE is print like this

```
REC
REC
REC
REC
```

Stored Procedure:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SP(Dy_File_Name    IN     VARCHAR2,
                                              SUPPLIER_CD     IN      VARCHAR2,
                                              EXT_PHARMA_ID   IN OUT    VARCHAR2,
                                              FLAG_VALUE      IN     VARCHAR2)
    AS

            CLREF            SYS_REFCURSOR;

        TYPE REC_TYP IS RECORD

           (

           AB                 VARCHAR2(256) ,
           AB1                VARCHAR2(256) ,  
           AB2                NUMBER(20),
           REC_STAT           VARCHAR2(9),
           VER_DOSAGE         VARCHAR2(20),

        OPEN CLREF FOR ('SELECT
                  S.ABC AS AB,
              S.ABC1 AS AB1,
              S.ABC2 AS AB2,
                  S.VERBOSE_DOSAGE                AS VER_DOSAGE,
                  CASE WHEN S.DEL_IND = 1 AND H.DEL_IND = 0 THEN ''DEL''
                       WHEN S.DEL_IND = 1 AND H.DEL_IND IS NULL THEN ''DEL_IGNR''
                       WHEN S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH <> H.DETL_CLMNS_HASH THEN ''UPDT''
                       WHEN S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH = H.DETL_CLMNS_HASH THEN ''DUPL''
                       WHEN S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH = S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH THEN ''REC''
                       WHEN H.DETL_CLMNS_HASH IS NULL THEN ''NEW''
                       ELSE ''ERR'' END AS REC_STAT

                FROM
                  (SELECT stg.*,
                    row_number() over ( partition BY key_clmns_hash, rx_dspnsd_dt, del_ind ORDER BY 1) AS RN
                  FROM  '   || Dy_File_Name || '   stg
                  ) s
                LEFT JOIN ps_pharmacy p ON s.extrnl_pharmacy_id = p.extrnl_pharmacy_id  
                LEFT JOIN ps_rx_hist H
                ON h.key_clmns_hash        = s.key_clmnS_hash
                AND h.rx_dspnsd_dt         = s.rx_dspnsd_dt
                AND s.supplier_pharmacy_cd = h.SUPPLIER_PHARMACY_CD
                WHERE s.RN                 = 1')


        LOOP


              FETCH CLREF  INTO REC;
              EXIT WHEN CLREF%NOTFOUND;

            dbms_output.put_line(REC.REC_STAT);    

              IF (REC.REC_STAT = 'UPDT')   
              THEN

                  L_UPD_COUNT := L_UPD_COUNT + 1;

              ELSIF (REC.REC_STAT = 'DUPL' ) -- DUPLICATE
              THEN

                    L_DUP_COUNT := L_DUP_COUNT + 1;

              ELSIF REC.REC_STAT = 'DEL' THEN-- DELETION

                      L_DEL_COUNT := L_DEL_COUNT +1;

              ELSIF REC.REC_STAT = 'DEL_IGNR' THEN  
                        SRC_ID := SRC_FILE_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;

              END IF;

        END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Since it is printing REC I assume that the following condition in your CASE statement is getting satisfied WHEN S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH = S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH THEN ''REC'' and hence your DBMS_OUTPUT is printing REC. Further, you have not handled this condition  IF (REC.REC_STAT = 'REC')  in your IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

By looking into your code I can see few pointers missing in the procedure. This case can only occur when there is `null` or "blank" for the `REC_STAT` field.

First print the dynamic sql and then try to run it and check the values. Hope these are helpful.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SP(
    Dy_File_Name  IN VARCHAR2,
    SUPPLIER_CD   IN VARCHAR2,
    EXT_PHARMA_ID IN OUT VARCHAR2,
    FLAG_VALUE    IN VARCHAR2)
AS
  CLREF SYS_REFCURSOR;
TYPE REC_TYP
IS
  RECORD
  (
    AB         VARCHAR2(256) ,
    AB1        VARCHAR2(256) ,
    AB2        NUMBER(20),
    REC_STAT   VARCHAR2(9),
    VER_DOSAGE VARCHAR2(20)
    );
REC REC_TYP; --Was missing
BEGIN        -- was missing
    OPEN CLREF FOR 
    'SELECT                  
        S.ABC AS AB,              
        S.ABC1 AS AB1,              
        S.ABC2 AS AB2,                  
        S.VERBOSE_DOSAGE                AS VER_DOSAGE,                  
        CASE WHEN S.DEL_IND = 1 AND H.DEL_IND = 0 THEN ''DEL''                       
        WHEN S.DEL_IND = 1 AND H.DEL_IND IS NULL THEN ''DEL_IGNR''                       
        WHEN S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH <> H.DETL_CLMNS_HASH THEN ''UPDT''                       
        WHEN S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH = H.DETL_CLMNS_HASH THEN ''DUPL''                       
        WHEN S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH = S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH THEN ''REC''                       
        WHEN H.DETL_CLMNS_HASH IS NULL THEN ''NEW''                       
        ELSE ''ERR'' END AS REC_STAT                

        FROM                  
        (SELECT stg.*,                    
        row_number() over ( partition BY key_clmns_hash, rx_dspnsd_dt, del_ind ORDER BY 1) AS RN                  
        FROM  ' || Dy_File_Name ||
        '   stg                  
        ) s                
        LEFT JOIN ps_pharmacy p ON s.extrnl_pharmacy_id = p.extrnl_pharmacy_id                  
        LEFT JOIN ps_rx_hist H                
        ON h.key_clmns_hash        = s.key_clmnS_hash                
        AND h.rx_dspnsd_dt         = s.rx_dspnsd_dt                
        AND s.supplier_pharmacy_cd = h.SUPPLIER_PHARMACY_CD                
        WHERE s.RN                 = 1';
    LOOP
      FETCH CLREF INTO REC;
      EXIT WHEN CLREF%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line(REC.REC_STAT); --Try to print any other entity returned by the dynamic sql
      IF (REC.REC_STAT    = 'UPDT') THEN
        L_UPD_COUNT      := L_UPD_COUNT + 1;
      ELSIF (REC.REC_STAT = 'DUPL' ) -- DUPLICATE
        THEN
        L_DUP_COUNT     := L_DUP_COUNT + 1;
      ELSIF REC.REC_STAT = 'DEL' THEN-- DELETION
        L_DEL_COUNT     := L_DEL_COUNT +1;
      ELSIF REC.REC_STAT = 'DEL_IGNR' THEN
        SRC_ID          := SRC_FILE_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above by Avrajit, please modify the code and also I can see that in your code in `case` statement:
`WHEN S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH = S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH THEN ''REC''`

because of the above condition you are getting the output as `REC`, this statement is always true.